# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. 3

Tags: c#-4.0

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

an error generated from a string conversion to date
an error generated from a string conversion to date
an error generated from a string conversion to date
an error generated from a string conversion to date

```
 sql = "select * from PROGRAMME_PREVISIONNEL where id_organisation= " + id_org + " and      
      ID_SYSTEME_HYDRAULIQUE= " + id_sys + " order by DATE_PROGRAMME";
        IList<object[]> progremmePrevionnelOrdered = 
    session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).List<object[]>();

        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = progremmePrevionnelOrdered.Count;
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

        string syid = null;
        string date = null;

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows =
            (from prog in progremmePrevionnelOrdered

             select new
             {
                 cell = new string[] {
                     prog[1].ToString(),

                     syid = prog[6].ToString(),
                     date = DateTime.ParseExact(prog[4].ToString().Substring(10),  
                   "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()


                 }
             }).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to take the first ten characters not the sub-string which starts at the 10th character.

Then you have to use

```
prog[4].ToString().Substring(0, 10)
```

instead of

```
prog[4].ToString().Substring(10)
```

here

```
date = DateTime.ParseExact(prog[4].ToString().Substring(0, 10),  
               "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()
```

Apart from that

- why do you convert the parsed `DateTime` back to string at all?
- i would strongly suggest to use sql-parameters to avoid sql-injection.

Comment: with : date = DateTime.ParseExact(prog[4].ToString().Substring(0,10), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")   thanks you a lot